# use enum as generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have an enum `day`

```
public enum DAY { SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY}
```

I want to create a generic interface so that for each day I want to have a different implementation

```
public interface DayLogic<T>
{
  void doLogic();
}
```

I want `<T>` to be a value of `DAY` `enum`
for example

```
public class WednesdayLogic implements DayLogic<DAY.WEDNESDAY>
{
   @Override
   public void doLogic()
   {}    
}
```

is it possible or is there any alternate flow to do so?

Comment: There is nothing in `DayLogic` that uses `T`. Why do you need the generic parameter in the first place?

Comment: Generics are for types. Day.WEDNESDAY is not a type. It's an instance

Comment: There's [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) since Java 8, worth a try using that for your logic.

Comment: Generics are a way to specify certain variables during runtime (example `class<T extends Number>` can be instantiated with any type extending `Number`). In your case you already know the type `DAY`, meaning you dont need generics, and can simply implement the interface instead. I am wondering though, what do you want to achieve? Do you want to select a certain logic with an enum-type? Maybe you can elaborate a bit more so we can understand the situation better.

Comment: @n247s I want each item in the `enum` to have different logic, so that I dont need to loop over enum value or check a condition if it matches the enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can achieve this concept by:

```
public enum DAY
{
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY
}
```

**Day Logic interface and Factory initializer**

```
public interface DayLogic
{
    void doLogic();

    public static class Factory
    {
        public static DayLogic getDayLogic(DAY day)
        {
            if (DAY.WEDNESDAY.equals(day))
            {
                return new WednesdayLogic();
            }
            // ...
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**WednesdayLogic Class:**

```
public class WednesdayLogic implements DayLogic
{
    final DAY day = DAY.WEDNESDAY;

    @Override
    public void doLogic()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Problem is that Enum Day is a value, not a class.

Edit: Thanks to @daniu I am adding how it was to be used:
DayLogic dayLogic = DayLogic.Factory.getDayLogic(DAY.WEDNESDAY);

Comment: I would suggest a factory method instead of a factory class if you do it like this - I don't know why you would want several factory instances. It might also provide cached instances rather than creating a new one for each invocation, depending on whether the logic has a state (doubtful imo). I'd also probably put it in `DAY`, not `DayLogic` because that introduces a new unecessary dependency.

Comment: a) can it be done better? definitely, I wanted to communicate the concept.
b) I am not sure that how there are going to be several instances of a static class?

Comment: @sadeez A `static` class is an inner class for which you don't need an instance of the outer class to create it, but you still need to create instances. It can be confusing due to the `static` meaning for variables that they only exist once. Just use your `Factory` in some sample code and you see you need to create an instance. It would work well with a singleton though, same effect as factory method.

Comment: Shed more light on "but you still need to create instances". I am not able to understand how multiple instances of factory will be created?

Comment: @sadeez just create some client code using the class you posted. You'll need to do something like `DayLogic.Factory factory = new DayLogic.Factory(); factory.getDayLogic(DAY.MONDAY);`, ie create an instance. And you'll be able to create more than one: `DayLogic.Factory f1 = new DayLogic.Factory(); DayLogic.Factory f2 = new DayLogic.Factory(); System.out.println(f1 == f2);`

Comment: @daniu I noticed that static keyword was missing from the function, so I have edited and added it
Thanks!

Comment: @sadeez Haha yes now it's the factory method I suggested in my original comment ^^ Now the enclosing `Factory` class is kind of pointless though, but I guess that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 4):

Since there are already answers to your original question, here's what you can do that should fit your use case: since an `enum` is just a (restricted) `class`, it can implement an `interface`, which looks like what you need:

```
public enum DAY implements DayLogic { 
 SUNDAY {
  public void doLogic() {
   // sunday logic implementation
  }
 }, 
 MONDAY{
  public void doLogic() {
   // monday logic implementation
  }
 }, 
 // ...
}
```

You can then use it like

```
DAY day = decideDay();
day.doLogic();
```

If you don't like the individual values having the method (I don't), you can do something like

```
public enum DAY implements DayLogic {
 SUNDAY(new SundayLogic()),
 MONDAY(new MondayLogic()),
 // ...
 ;

 private DayLogic logicDelegate; // or Runnable, it's the same signature

 private DAY(DayLogic logic) {
  logicDelegate = logic;
 }

 public doLogic() {
  logicDelegate.run();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from daniu is one option: the enum can implement an interface, and you do all in the interface. Especially using a constructor with DayLogic is nice.

Often that DayLogic is a later, uncoupled phenomenon. In that case use an [**`EnumMap`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) from the enum to your logic.

```
public class Dayly {
    private final Map<Day, DayLogic> logicMap = new EnumMap<>(Day.class);

    public void putLogic(Day day, DayLogic logic) {
        logicMap.put(day, logic);
    }
    ...
}
```